# Explaining The Quantum Mechanics Weirdness

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, time-dilation

Academic replies only; I would like feedback on this, so yes i am asking you to poke holes in it, it is about explaining the time weirdness of quantum mechanics and how particles behave.

When the universe was created the universe created time, hence time is dependant on matter in the universe, this is why space and time are interwoven together, which we now call spacetime, and so if you bend space you change the flow of time, the earth does this all the time it bends space to create gravity at 9.8m/s and with this it changes the flow of time slightly, time flows faster near centres of gravity in the universe, because of this fact.

This has been demonstrated by noting that atomic clocks at differing altitudes (and thus different gravitational potential) will eventually show different times, it is called Gravitational time dilation.

when you unravel the building blocks of space and go subatomic you unravel the things that make up our flow of time, the further you go subatomicaly the more timeless you become because the building blocks of time in our space "thin out", there is less of them subatomicaly so subatomic particles at different depths experience different flows of time...remembering gravitational time dilation this is the opposite.

If time didn't exist everything would occur simultaneously, time defines the increments of life (so to speak) which is something that has been theorised for a long time now, so keeping in mind the more subatomic you go the more timeless you are this is why subatomic particles behave the way they do, they appear everywhere at once and simultaneously, and are in all states at the same time.

This is only by our observation of them because we move in our flow of time while they move in their flow of time so it just appears that everything is simultaneous.©

Comment: Acedemic reply: I have no idea what you are talking about, and I don't see a question here.

Comment: Another academic reply: This doesn't seem to address anything about quantum mechanics.

Comment: I'm suprised you can read let alone spell the word, try following instructions instead of jumping at the chance to insult someone.

Comment: Well, what aspect of quantum mechanics does your pet theory address that cannot be explained by the past 100 years of experiments and theory? Being rude does not help when dealing with real physicists who work on real issues. But, tell us how this helps us understand something in a different way and we will listen.

Comment: The question was to tell me how it falls apart, I'm not here trying to help  you. You should also correct yourself on who was being rude to who.

Comment: Related: [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/what-is-time-does-it-flow-and-if-so-what-defines-its-direction)

Comment: In my opinion, it's a real question that can be improved in such a way to be worth reopening. Some people who never heard of quantum mechanics before find quantum mechanics magic just like we would find it magic to encounter a real ghost and might want an intuitive explanation of why we can't prove the universe should follow classical physics. I asked a similar question myself at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427419/could-it-be-really-possible-to-go-through-a-tunnel-into-a-new-universe-like-in-t but it asks whether stuff that contradicts the current theory can really happen.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for an academic critique; so this is what I would say to the editor if this were submitted to me for review:

This essay is primarily philosophical, and makes assertions about time, but provides no support for these statements; it lacks references and sufficient argument/demonstration.

It would be much improved by discussing some of the many published ideas about how time and space are emergent properties from the "quantum reality", but this essay doesn't seem to address any of the problems found, or the solutions offered.

Clarity of purpose is lacking; a typical academic essay starts with a statement of purpose, and ends with the conclusions which have been shown.  In this case the conclusion is inconsistent with Special & General Relativity, as there is no simultaneity of time, though perhaps this is just poorly worded.

Comment: thanks for the serious response, to address what you said briefly time is born out of quantum entanglement a number of papers have asserted this, the deeper you go sub atomically the less particles exist the less entanglement that exists hence the flow of time must be different. Also “time exists only where mass exists”.

Comment: @IbnMasud but how does that explain quantum mechanics? I'd also like to see a citation for "time is born out of quantum entanglement"

Comment: 1. Time From Quantum Entanglement: An Experimental Illustration
Abstract: In the last years several theoretical papers discussed if time can be an emergent propertiy deriving from quantum correlations. Here, to provide an insight into how this phenomenon can occur, we present an experiment that illustrates Page and Wootters’ mechanism of “static” time, and Gambini et al...

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4691v1.pdf     RE. the quote i don't remember which physicist said it.

Comment: How spacetime is built by quantum entanglement  http://phys.org/news/2015-05-spacetime-built-quantum-entanglement.html

Comment: Another Quote: “Space-time, is just a geometrical picture of how stuff in the quantum system is entangled.” Mark Van Raamsdonk.