# Is "time" a singular dimension or multiple dimensions?

Tags: time, spacetime-dimensions

We know of x, y, and z dimensions. We also know of "time"... Another dimension we are aware of, which is a "non-physical dimension" called a "temporal dimension". Now, we all look at "time" as a "single dimension". We all know "time"... has 3 different aspects to it (past, present, and future).

What if time is constructed of "multiple dimensions"?

Is "time" actually a singular dimension or is it just a hologram of the past, present, and future?

> **Hologram:** a three-dimensional image formed by the interference of light beams from a laser or other coherent light source.

Comment: Time is just a coordinate like the other three spatial coordinates; nothing special right?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Kinda right, apart from the fact we are (severely) limited  in moving around in that co-ordinate : )

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you are standing upright aligned with the $z$ axis and facing along the $y$ axis, then the $x$ axis is to the left of you, at your position and to the right of you. But we don't say there are three $x$ axes. The $x$ axis simply comes in from $-\infty$ from your left, through your position and then off away to $+\infty$ on your right.

In exactly the same way the time axis comes from your past, through your position and off into your future. The time axis is a single axis [just like the three spatial axes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/what-is-time-does-it-flow-and-if-so-what-defines-its-direction).

Answer (score 3):

[Itzhak Bars](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1004.0688) proposes a two-time physics. This means the spacetime(s) metric is of the form
$$
ds^2 = dt^2 + du^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2.
$$
The anti-de Sitter spacetime is a subspace of this type of metric as well, where a constant surface is a hyperboloid. A hyperboloid in 5 dimensional space times is given by
$$
t^2 + u^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 1.
$$

The Lorentz symmetry of spacetime has the orthogonal group structure $SO(3,1)$, and if there were two-times the structure of the spacetime would be $SO(3,2)$. Anti-de Sitter spacetime is a subspace of a five dimensional spacetime with two-times. This is $AdS_4 = SO(3,2)/SO(3,1)$. The quotient can be interpreted as meaning the five dimensional spacetime equivalent under Lorentz generators.

Answer (score 1):

Time is not a combination of a past, present, and future dimensions, but rather a one-dimensional axis, where the past and future are dependent on the present for definition, and the present is a particle's position in time. In the theory of relativity, a particle has position $(x,y,z,t)$, where $(x,y,z)$ is the particle's position in space, and $t$ is the particle's position in time. The past of the particle is defined as all values of $t$ less the particle's $t$ value, the present is the particle's $t$ value, and the future is any $t$ value greater then the particle's $t$ value.