# How can we determine time flows in one direction?

Tags: time, perception, arrow-of-time

Suppose that time could flow in either direction, forward or reverse, similar to a movie. How could our brain possibly record that time had moved backwards? Would there be any way to tell if time had run forwards and backwards countless numbers of times? Isn't it true that our brains only function in one direction of time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)

Comment: I feel like one of the answers there goes well with my question, but it's a different question.

Comment: Or should I say, multiple answers.