# Can time flow backwards?

Tags: time, arrow-of-time

Is there any equations in physics or laws that say time can flow backwards instead of forward?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)