# Is there something like Anti-time?

Tags: spacetime, time, antimatter, time-reversal-symmetry, arrow-of-time

According to mathematics, everything has its opponent. Suppose something is $x$. Let $x = 5$, then $x^2 = 25$, and again if $x^2 = 25$, then x may be positive or negative. In the same way, let $x = time$, then is there something like $antitime$?

Comment: [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/37364)

Comment: "According to mathematics, everything has anti nature", what?

Comment: Everything has anti nature because Everything can be written as x.  X may be anything it may be mass or any other property. If x = 5. Then X^2 = 5^2 =25 then if we try to solve the equation x^2=25 we will get x=5 or x=-5. It means there is something which is -5.

Comment: In the theoretical physics there is the existence of negative mass

Comment: Just because something exists mathematically doesn't mean it exists physically.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the world of mathematical physics, there is, and here is an example.

A charged particle traveling forward in time from one point to another may be considered indistinguishable from its *antiparticle counterpart* (identical to it except carrying the opposite charge) traveling between those two same points, only going *backwards* in time.

A fairly good exposition of this is contained in Feynman's Dirac Memorial Lecture, which can be viewed on youtube or read in the book of the same name which contains it.