# Why does time flow?

Tags: time

People have explained [how](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/) time flows but not why time flows or how time flow is possible at all. How does science explain time flow?

Comment: Check that this question has already been asked here. Please, have a seach before asking new questions. Thank you.  [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)

Comment: Saying entropy answers the question of flow is like Magritte Treachery of Images. You don't have flow so how do you create entropy? Its a nice narrative without any real essence.

Comment: Are you questioning the possibility  of time flow because of the block universe? [My answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557219/37364) discusses that.

Comment: The question of *how* time flows is the only meaningful one that can be answered by physics. We don't know *why* anything happens and the purpose of creating mathematical models in physics isn't to answer this question. We are only able to know *that* things work a particular way, not why nature "chose" them to be that way.

Comment: @mmesser314 the block theory doesn't explain flow, but i suppose you did say that any lambda label for flow was meaningless. Does this statement mean science doesn't have a concept for flow of time?

Comment: @charlie I suppose that's the answer I wanted then.

Comment: @Charlie Better said, we stopped asking *why* questions in physics a long time ago. The ancient Greeks did it, we haven't done so for centuries now. That's the main difference between science back then, much closer to philosophy, and science now.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft its clearly not the same and its not a duplicate since no one had answered why, only how. Since people keep falsely labeling it as a duplicate the text on the post actually states "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." If you have an issue it sounds like you need to post it to a meta rather than to me.

Comment: @Solomon still doesn't make it a duplicate, however, or unanswerable, since I got an answer. You might try to argue that its unrelated to science, but a lot of theoretical science discusses metaphysical properties and i don't see how this is any different.