# Are there particles that carry time?

Tags: entropy, time, virtual-particles

As every event in the universe can be reduced to interaction between particles via the 4 fundamental forces, can the same be applied to time? Could the flow of time be reduced to a particle that causes an instant of time, or is time an emergent phenomenon of the fabric or the nature of space? Or could time be an emergent phenomenon as a result of virtual particles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/what-is-time-does-it-flow-and-if-so-what-defines-its-direction)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that time is a dimension analogous to the three dimensions of space, and does not need a particle to "carry" it any more than "North" needs a particle to carry it.