# Entropy and time asymmetry

Tags: statistical-mechanics, energy-conservation, symmetry, entropy

I have learned in Lagrangian Mechanics that the existence of time symmetries makes energy conserved. But from thermodynamics, we know that entropy introduces the forward arrow of time, i.e., the time asymmetry. We do know that energy is also conserved in thermodynamics. Where am I missing the point? Can someone connect the dots for me?

Comment: [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/37364)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Time translation symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_translation_symmetry) does not preclude an [arrow of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time). The former, which assumes that the laws of physics do not change over time (not that time must move forward), is assumed in both Lagrangian mechanics and thermodynamics and underlies the law of conservation of energy.

Comment: Can you elaborate it thoroughly?

Comment: If I can. Which part is unclear?