# Are we misunderstanding time?

Tags: general-relativity, time, observers, perception

I think time is a constantly and uniformly flowing thing made by us to compare and relate different events with each other by it. It help us to predict  things at different points in this flow. It forms the basic framework joining all events together. It makes things convenient and helps to do more complex things. Please tell me whether I am right? Then how could time run slower when moving fast or in a strong gravitational field?

Comment: You are talking about two completely different things : (1) The human *perception* of time and (2) time as it is used in the theory of general relativity.  This site only deals with the physics of time, so only your last sentence would (IMO) be on topic here.

Comment: Then what is real interpretation of time? how would it make 
any sense without any physical interpretation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)

Answer (score 5):

Imagine that you and I have a pair of lead-lined suitcases, each containing an identical lump of some radioactive element.

1. If we sit next to each other holding our suitcases, then our lumps will decay at precisely the same rate.
2. If you pick up your suitcase, run around in circles for a while,
   and then come back and compare with me, then your lump will have
   decayed less than mine.
3. If you pick up your suitcase, take it to the top of a mountain for a while, and then come back and compare with me, then your lump will have decayed more than mine.

In each case, *you* won't notice any difference in the decay rate of your lump, regardless of your state of motion or location - you see a steady rate of decay, and only notice a discrepancy when you sit back down next to me and compare lumps. You can wrap whatever words you'd like around this phenomenon, but this is what people mean when they say that time passes differently for different observers.

Comment: Could not it be like that the flow of time does not change but anything else causes the rate of the decay and your perception of flowing of time equally change so you don't notice any change in the decay rate of that radioactive material.

Comment: @BIDISHRANJANDas The essence of relativity is that *every* physical system will evolve just like the lump of radioactive material. If we start with synchronized wristwatches and you run around while I sit still, yours will have ticked fewer times when we meet again. Your heart will beat fewer times, your cells will divide fewer times, and all of that is what I *mean* by the flow of time being different. If you want to use different words then you may, but I find that most people get hung up on poorly defined, vague terminology, which is why I used physical, tangible examples.

Comment: But some equations don't include time?

Comment: Is there anything absolute flowing thing in the universe which does not change anywhere? and if there is no such thing do we need to make one?

Comment: @BIDISHRANJANDas The existence of an “absolutely flowing thing” would not be consistent with relativity. Since relativity has been validated by every experiment ever performed, my answer would be no, there is no such thing, nor is such a thing possible. We’re now outside the scope of the question, though - you asked “how does time flow differently for different observers” and I did my best to answer. I hope it was helpful.