# Why do i get two different time in same frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Suppose I am standing in a station with a light clock(1).(A clock where light is bouncing up and down with a height of h.).Lets calculate the time seeing light clock(1) t=h/c (here c is the speed of light) and a train is passing through the station with a velocity of v.And there is another light clock(2) inside the train.Lets calculate the time seeing light clock(2).Now we get t=D/c. And here D is not equal to h since the train is
moving and light needs to pass some extra distance.So we get two different time in same reference frame.Why?

Comment: Time is very different from what your everyday experience and classical physics would lead you to expect. See [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/37364)

Comment: What, exactly, don't you understand?

Comment: There are a ton of questions and answers about the light clock here. I marked this as a duplicate of one. If that one doesn’t answer your question then please read a few more. If none of them answer it then please write a new question, link to the ones you read, and explain what is missing from the linked questions and answers

Comment: I had lunch today at 1pm and dinner at 6pm, though I sat perfectly still all day.  How can these events occur at different times in the same reference frame?