# Can we think of entropy and time as the same thing?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, time, time-dilation, arrow-of-time

My assumption is that entropy is a change in the distribution of energy in one direction. The universe is a system going from low to high entropy. Can time be described without the change of entropy?  Is our perception of time really just the perception of motion, caused by entropy?

Thought experiment: If every atom in the universe was "paused" in a certain state, so that we essentially paused entropy, we of course would not be able to "perceive" the "passage of time", but the question is, is time still "ticking"? Do our mathematical models show that time would continue in a case like this? Or is the passage of time deeply connected to the flow of entropy, in that you can't have one without the other?

And if time and entropy are connected in this way, can entropy be described as relativistic? Can time-dilation be described as the apparent speeding up or slowing down of entropy?

Or am I deeply confused?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/50583

Comment: Yeah that almost answers the question but I still think mines different enough that it deserves its own answer.

Comment: @hermancain in this case you should try to edit the question ho make clear what's the novelty here. Then, it can be reopened. Are you reading "The order of time" by C. Rovelli?