# Was "flow of time" equally fast during the life of universe? Is Doppler Effect the only interpretation of "shift to red"?

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion, universe, doppler-effect

I'm an IT developer and recently I created a project where I tried to send signals between two threads in a slowing down environment. I simulated two points with their own clocks and tried to send a signal of 1Hz to the other. I programmed clocks to gradually (lineary) slow down (from it's perspective it was still 1Hz but from another point perspective it was less as some time past until the signal arrived and the personal clock slowed down already) and I left the signal speed (something like light) and distance between them untouched. What I observed was "shift to blue".

Instantly I thought about "shift to red" as a proof for universe expanding. Isn't is possible that "shift to red" is caused not by Doppler effect, but simply that it was being generated slower eons ago? Like everything sped up (what we cannot detect as our detector also sped up). And the further we look the slower everything was processed? Recently I've heard that in fact we observe distant galaxies in slow motion. Everywhere I check "shift to red" and it's interpretation as Doppler effect is treated as a main proof of a Big Bang. Wouldn't we see a similar effect in a static universe (regarding space) where time flow is not constant but it speeds up in a linear way? Are there any observations that proove that, I don't know how to describe it better, time flow speed was constant during the life of universe?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/2451 and links therein.

Comment: As explained in the link above, physics does not specify any sense in which time flows.

Comment: [My answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557219/37364) in the link above discusses how flowing time is consistent with the block universe. Also I have read somewhere that the expansion of the universe can be recast as a changing rate of time. I have no idea where, so it isn't very helpful.