Non-linear time and concurrent perceptions of reality
I am asking about what the fact that a photograph and a physical space can exist, in what we perceive to be different moments in linear time (with the photo being made from what we regard as our primary, momentary reality) reveals about the creation of the past, present and future space, time and reality. And I want an answer about the physics of this, for example: how does a photograph I have in my hand now, showing a supposed time and space from the past, create that time and space? Considering time is now not thought to be linear anymore by many physicians.

Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/831510/2451 Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/2451 and links therein.

Go have a walk in the mud, then look behind you. Do you have the same questions about your footprints? They show another time and another space, just like a photography.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics.

Do physicians no longer consider time to be linear? Perhaps that explains why I have to wait so long to see my GP.

Hmm Stéphane, but that’s not really the same is it because:

A photo is just something produced by a camera. The existence of a photo of a thing has nothing to do with the existence of that thing or any other thing.

You seem very confused. To begin, consider how vision works. Your eye has a lens that focuses light from the subject of your gaze so that it forms an image on your retina. Your brain interprets the image to create the visual experience. A photo consists of a large number of coloured dots- loosely speaking- the pattern of which matches the image formed by the lens of a camera. The photo does not ‘create that time and space’. When you look at a photo your eye creates an image of it on your retina. Your brain interprets that image as a resemblance of the subject of the photograph.

Yes I know, but you haven’t talked about the particles in the site of the photo was taken and the particles in the photo and their relationship. And you haven’t talked about how a photo can exist for a person, before the actual place exists, in their perception, through being observed. How is it the two match? That I can identify a place that was previously unknown to me as looking like a photo?

That's nothing to do with physics. If I show you a photo of a place you have never visited, your brain creates an image of the place, just as it would create an image of it if you were looking at it in the flesh.

Ok so how does that explain time? Why can we say that a photo of a place and time we weren’t  present in, and another person was, show the same thing?

It has nothing to do with time, per se. A camera captures an image of a place in the same way that the eye of a person does- light from the objects in the place is focussed by a lens. What is mysterious about that?

That the image can be kept, potentially forever. What got me thinking about this was a book called the holographic universe which is about the writings of Niels Bohr.

So? With a digital camera the "image" is just a string of bits on a hard drive, not a physical representation of time or space or anything physical. Your brain interprets this string of bits, when rendered using a PNG/JPEG reader, as an image of a place, but I don't have to actually go to that place at a particular time to create a string of bits that will convince your brain equally-well that you're looking at that place at that time (this is called CGI). The Universe does not care about anyone's perception of it.

I think it is interesting that you are all distinguishing between the reality outside of the photo and that of the photo. They are both a part of our primary reality. And also, I talk about photography because just as with other forms of what we consider to be copies, recordings of reality, the “magic” we see of them is that they are ways of replicating the reality outside of them that we experience. In the holographic theory of the universe, it says that information is continually broken down, and that every piece of the universe contains all of the information to remake all of it.

They have spent years trying to capture a photo of a particle as a particle and a wave and they finally have it but according to you guys that is nothing, it’s just something made up.


how does a photograph I have in my hand now, showing a supposed time and space from the past, create that time and space?

Having a photograph doesn't create anything.  It's just a photograph, nothing more, nothing less.

But what is”just a photograph”. What is the photo composed of which makes it resemble a real space and time? And what is the relationship between the real space and time of the actual site where the photo was taken and the photo?

@LewisMason You're talking about the human perception of an object, which is more like psychology and neuroscience than physics.  From a physics point of view, no time and space is captured or released or created by the photo.

Really? Well firstly, is there physics involved in our perception of space and time? And secondly, why do we accept that photography is able to contain information about that space and time?

Again, you're talking about issues that are outside the scope of physics, certainly as this site deals with it.  You might feel happier over on [philosophy.se].
